# What is the recommended way to organize Yocto project repository(-ies)?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

**How do you typically organize Yocto project during development?**

The typical approach I saw was to divide project into following repositories and connect them using Android repo tool:

- workspace project (containing repo manifest.xml)
- build
- meta-bsp-layer
- poky
- meta-openembedded
- and so on...

What I do not like here:

- awful project history (in fact there are only magic git hash changes in manifest.xml)
- additional tool to learn (repo)
- bigger number of repositories

Because most of collegaues are git beginners (do not want to add them new complexity introduced by repo), our current projects looks like:

```
workspace_productA.git
|-> build
|-> sources
     |-> meta-bsp-layer
```

poky, meta-openembedded and other upstream layers are just cloned manually or via some bash script.

All most frequently changeable content (build, meta-bsp-layer) is placed in flat repository and clean history. 
But I am wondering if this approach is scalable.

I would appreciate to hear about your solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Android repo tool is indeed one way of organizing and setting up the required Yocto project repositories. I prefer the approach taken by [yoe-distro](https://github.com/YoeDistro/yoe-distro) and also recently used it to create BSP for our project.

Comment: I found repo easier to use than git submodules, but these work both quite well.